# lodash _.template() wrong output

Tags: javascript, frontend, lodash, templating

I'm learning lodash now. My goal is to output an array of users to my html table using lodash template. However, I can't figure out why my template doesn't work.

**my users**

```
var users = [
    { 'user': 'fred', 'active': false, 'age': 40 },
    { 'user': 'pebbles', 'active': false, 'age': 1 },
    { 'user': 'barney', 'active': true, 'age': 36 }
];
```

**my template**

```
let template4 = _.template('<ul>' +
    '<% _.forEach(users, function(user) { %>' +
    '<li><%- user.user %></li>' +
    '<% }); %>' +
    '</ul>');

let template4Result = template4({ 'users': users }); // I expect => '<ul><li>fred</li><li>pebbles</li><li>barney</li></ul>'

console.log(template4Result);// => '<ul></ul>'
```

I can't figure out how I should design my template so it loops through my collection and adds some html code to every user in it.

Comment: Are you sure your `users` are being passed in correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code works; Below is a running snippet.

```js
var users = [
    { 'user': 'fred', 'active': false, 'age': 40 },
    { 'user': 'pebbles', 'active': false, 'age': 1 },
    { 'user': 'barney', 'active': true, 'age': 36 }
];

let template4 = _.template('<ul>' +
    '<% _.forEach(users, function(user) { %>' +
    '<li><%- user.user %></li>' +
    '<% }); %>' +
    '</ul>');

let template4Result = template4({ 'users': users });
console.log(template4Result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that the `users` variable you're passing into the template has no items in it. So you're not getting the data you're expecting.

If you're retrieving your users asynchronously (via an AJAX call), you'll need to use a callback to only generate your template once the ajax call has returned. Below is a **pseudo**-example (`ajax` is not a real interface).

```
ajax.get(function(users) {
    // this would be the "success" callback
    // we're now able to render the template since we have the data

    let template4Result = template4({ 'users': users });
})
```

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Something was wrong with my variable. I was using `userModel = users;` instead of `userModel = _.take(users, 300);`. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
let template4 = _.template('<ul>' +
'<% _.forEach(users, function(value, key) { %>' +
'<li><%- value.user %></li>' +
'<% }); %>' +
'</ul>');
```